# Microkernel or Dependency Injection Container in C++

Tags: c++, architecture, microkernel

Form C# and Java I know Microkernels also known as Dependency Injection Container. The main goal of them is to seperate the interface from the implementation.

In C# it works like this

```
register<IXYTask>(Type task);
..
Task xyTask = resolve<IXYTask>();
```

I think as C++ has no Reflection and you can't pass, save or instanciate a type. Is there a possibility in C++ to get a similair result?

Comment: Where do you think your sample code uses reflection?

Comment: For the instanciation of the Type task.